# Typeorm find returns 404

Tags: nestjs, endpoint, typeorm

i have a find() query to my database,  which i want to be able return a list of all my questions in that table.

The serivce

```
async findAll() : Promise<Question[] >{
        return await this.questionRepository.find();
    }
```

The controller

```
@Get('/all')
    async returnAllQuestions(): Promise<Question[] > {
      return await this.questionsService.findAll();
    }
```

The question entity

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({name: 'Questions'})
export class Question {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  questionID: number;

  @Column()
  question: string;

}
```

There are records inside my table
[image]

and the types are set as follows
[image]

However when i call the /all endpoint i get a 404 not found error.
[image]

I have no clue what is wrong, I can call an findById endpoint, using uestionRepository.findOneOrFail(id); which is working fine, but the all method keeps failing'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mistake was that i had other endpont.         ```@Get('/:id')
    findOne(@Param() params): Promise<Question> {
        return this.questionsService.findOneById(params.id);      
    }```         which was called when adding /all to the url. so the 'all' was considered as a parameter for that endpoint. It was solved by changing the other endpoint to @Get('/id:id')

Comment: can you add your service code too?